# Layout Background not applied in ActionBar(Transparent)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm having transparent actionbar and i just set a background image.
My Actionbar is now transparent but it doesn't shows the layout background image in actionbar. it shows like the image attached[image]

Please help me :-(
**Thanks in Advance!**

Answer (score 1):

Set below style to your action bar.

```
  <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
  </style>

 <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">#64000000</item>
</style>
```

or

Call setStackedBackgroundDrawable() on your ActionBar:

```
 getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
 actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
```